# Angularfire $remove function not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Maybe is a simple error but I can't detect it.

I have this script's in index

```
<head>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="angularfirebase">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script>FIREBASE KEY</script>
```

I inject this in app.js

```
angular.module('angularfirebase', ['ionic', 'angularfirebase.crud', 'firebase'])
```

And this in controller.js

```
angular.module('angularfirebase.crud', [])
     .controller('usersController', function ($scope) {
            var users = root.ref('/users/');
            //Show All
            users.on("value", function (snapshot) {
                //No real time
                $scope.users = snapshot.val();
            });
            //Remove
            $scope.removeUser = function (id) {
                alert("Remove");
                $scope.users.$remove(id);
            };
        })
```

Finally I have this in users page

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, user) in users">
    CODE
<i class="ion-trash-a" title="Delete" ng-click="removeUser(id)"></i>
```

When I click remove function console.log show `TypeError: $scope.users.$remove is not a function`. ¿Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `remove` the `user` from `DataSnapshot` which is not possible. `DataSnapshot` is just a copy of the databse and used to read the data.

According to official [Firebase DataSnapshot Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot):

> A DataSnapshot is an efficiently generated, immutable copy of the data
>   at a Database location. It cannot be modified and will never change
>   (to modify data, you always call the set() method on a Reference
>   directly).

To `delete` the user, you need to do it using `database reference`, instead of `dataSnapshot`.

**Try this:**

```
users.child(id).remove().then(function() {//users is the user database reference
    console.log("Remove succeeded.")
})
.catch(function(error) {
   console.log("Remove failed: " + error.message)
});
```

i am assuming `id` is a `child` insid `users` which you are trying to `remove`.

For more information on `Remove`, Read [Firebase Database Reference#remove Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#remove)

Answer (score 0):

I fix this error using Angularfire and this

```
  $scope.removeUser = function (id) {
            var user = $firebaseObject(users);
            //Want to show item name
            var confirm = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                title: '<div><i class="ion-trash-a max"></i><div><h2>¿Are you sure?</h2></div>',
                subTitle: '<h4>The user <b>' + id + '</b> will be deleted.</h4>',
            });
            confirm.then(function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    user.$remove(id);
                }
            });
        }
    })
```

Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you look at my approach? It was a rectification of your approach.